# my custom css not loading with `wp_enqueue_script`

Tags: css, wordpress

I enqueued my `custom css` in my theme file, but it's not showing any results. When I check the source file i.e. **CTRL+U**, it's showing my `custom-css` file, but my `CSS` file is not working.

```
function child_theme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Awesome Font', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style('Bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_scripts_styles' );
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `wp_enqueue_script` to load the **stylesheet file**. Wordpress couldn't recognize your `css` file since you are linking with script.

Use this

```
function child_theme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Awesome Font', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style('Bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_scripts_styles' );
```

**Replace**

`wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );`

**With**

`wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );`

**For Reference Visit**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: oh I got it wrong. Thankx , couldn't see what I was doing. working now